# I am trying to do projection with simple subtract function but I am receiving error on $subtract mongodb can't $subtract string from string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to do subtract on mongodb but I am facing formatting issue

```
[{$match: {
 StrategyStatus: 1
}}, {$project: {
 TradingPair: 1,
 BotName: 1,
 TotalFees: 1,
 CapitalAmount: 1,
 TotalRealisedProfit: 1,
 PureProfit: {
  $subtract: [
   '$TotalRealisedProfit',
   '$TotalFees'
  ]
 }
}}]
```

I am tring to execute this query on MongoDB Compass

The error that I am receiving is

> PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: can't $subtract
> string from string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are in string format.

> Subtracts two numbers to return the difference, or two dates to return the difference in milliseconds, or a date and a number in milliseconds to return the resulting date.

You need to convert your string on the fly to integer `$toInt`

```
PureProfit: {
  $subtract: [

   {$toInt : '$TotalRealisedProfit'},
   {$toInt' : $TotalFees'}

  ]
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much I tried
{
 TradingPair: 1 ,
 BotName: 1,
 TotalFees: 1,
 CapitalAmount:1,
 TotalRealisedProfit: 1,
 PureProfit: { $subtract: [
  { $toDecimal: "$TotalRealisedProfit"} ,
  { $toDecimal: "$TotalFees"}]}
}